# StreamBuilder's Firebase query appears and disappears instantly

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am trying to query a **Stream** where the document should have '*UretimKurulum*' in '*unit*' array and the '*date*' should be equal or greater than today's date.

While streaming this query I do get the correct results that I want for a brief seconds and then it says 'No Data Available'.

[image: Database]

Below is the actual code:

```
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  final DateTime _now = DateTime.now();
  final String val = 'UretimKurulum';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object>>(
      stream: _db.collection('Schedule').where('date', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _now).where('unit', arrayContains: val).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: LinearProgressIndicator());
        } else {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: Text('No Data Available'));
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var docSnap = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                return Text(docSnap.id);
              },
            );
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

If I try to remove:

```
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: Text('No Data Available'));
          }
```

I get the following error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object>>>#0508a):
Unexpected null value.
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Could this issue be related with compound query indexing in Firestore? Debug Console doesn't displays a link to add the index.

Comment: Can you try adding `|| snapshot.data == null` to the line `if (!snapshot.hasData) {`. Not sure if it will have any effect, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @JaffaKetchup unfortunately it has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And indeed it was an indexing issue as @blaneyneil and myself stated previously.

The solution was to create a composite collection index from the Firebase Console and index the fields 'todoUnit' as Arrays and 'date' as Ascending.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First thing first

```
 //instead of DateTime 
 final DateTime _now = DateTime.now();
 //you should use Timestamp which is provided by Firebase Firestore
 final Timestamp timeNow = Timestamp.now();
```

and second thing

```
//instead of
where('unit', arrayContains: val)
//try this
where("unit", "arrayContains", val)
```

Hope it should work if doesn't then reply me I will try to find other solution.

Answer (score 1):

you'll get that blink when you haven't created the necessary indexes in Firestore.  you need to create indexes for any queries that involve >, >=, <, <=.  in your case, you should have something like the below in your firestore.indexes.json:

```
{
  "collectionGroup": "Schedule",
  "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldPath": "unit",
      "arrayConfig": "CONTAINS"
    },
    {
      "fieldPath": "date",
      "order": "ASCENDING"
    }
  ]
},
```

or, if you prefer, just do it manually from your Firestore console.

Answer (score 0):

0. **why you try remove the checkdata ?**, the UX in general standard should display no data if the data is null or empty. for avoid null, you can use elvis operator like `data ?? 'default-data'` or `data == null ? 'no-data' : 'found-data'`
1. good for datetime condition is using `DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch` instead of `DateTime.now()` **this optional but more precise data is effectively** [https://docs.w3cub.com/dart~2/dart-core/datetime/microsecondssinceepoch](https://docs.w3cub.com/dart%7E2/dart-core/datetime/microsecondssinceepoch)
2. you can try change

```
// instead of
       if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: Text('No Data Available'));
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var docSnap = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                return Text(docSnap.id);
              },
            );
          }
```

```
// try this
       if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: Text('No Data Available'));
       } 
       return ListView.builder(
           itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
           itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var docSnap = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
              return Text(docSnap.id);
           },
        );
```